# prettify-symbols-mode and multi-character replacements?

Tags: latex, string, display, prettify-symbols-mode

With `prettify-symbols-mode` it is possible to replace strings by a character, or a character composition, e.g.

```
;; \lambda → λ
(push '("\\lambda" . ?λ) prettify-symbols-alist)
```

Optionally, it allows combining multiple characters, which will be put on top of each other, e.g. in order to create an underline bold character,

```
(push '("\\mathbf x" . "xx_") prettify-symbols-alist)
```

But does Emacs also have a feature, that allows multi-character replacements, e.g. allowing a prettification

```
\section{Hello World}  → ###{Hello World} ?
```

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/34808

Comment: I didn't even know that you can underline and bold the symbol. Neat! Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by looking into the implementation of ``prettify-symbols-mode''.

```
   ;; Special form for section etc.
   (let ((spec '(("\\\\part\\b"          font-latex-sectioning-0-face "#")
                 ("\\\\chapter\\b"       font-latex-sectioning-1-face "##")
                 ("\\\\section\\b"       font-latex-sectioning-2-face "###")
                 ("\\\\subsection\\b"    font-latex-sectioning-3-face "####")
                 ("\\\\subsubsection\\b" font-latex-sectioning-4-face "#####")
                 ("\\\\paragraph\\b"     shadow "¶"))))
     (dolist (s spec)
       (let ((regexp (nth 0 s))
             (face (nth 1 s))
             (repl (nth 2 s)))
         (font-lock-add-keywords nil 
           `((,regexp 0 
               (prog1 ',face 
                 (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                   '(display ,repl)))))))))
   (push 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props) ;; Allow removal of display property by font-lock
   (push 'composition font-lock-extra-managed-props)
```

### How it works

- `font-lock-mode` uses regexp matching to find the keywords.
- When a keyword is found, the `prog1` part is evaluated; Its return value is used as face for the regexp, but it can also be used for side-effects.
- Using the region found by the regexp matcher (`match-beginning`, `match-end`), a `display` test property is applied, which visually replaces the region by the given string.
- Font-lock mode must be told, that it should remove the display and composition properties, by adding the symbols to `font-lock-extra-managed-props`. Without this, the composition/display properties would remain after editing the text, such that it doesn't match the keyword anymore.
- Sadly, this can conflict with other *'display* properties, such as the `(raise FLOAT)` property used by AucTeX for subscripts and superscripts. In such cases some tinkering is required, in order to create a *'display* string, which itself inherits the *display/raise* property, and is applied *after* superscript fontification, since AucTeX is not aware of such customizations. You'd end up with a string object with nested display properties, such as

  ```
  ;; (buffer-string)
  #("Hello Original Content World" 6 22
     (display
       #("Replacement" 0 11
          (display
            (raise -0.5)))))
  ```