# prog-mode-hook not recognizing .ex files in user-config

Tags: spacemacs, config, prettify-symbols-mode, prog-mode

I'm trying to display prettify-symbols-mode to display for certain characters. I would like for this minor mode to be enabled across all programming languages - thus prog-mode. When I navigate to a .ex file it is not giving me the expected outcome (ie. => should display as ⇒). Code is below:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()


      (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)

      (setq powerline-default-separator 'arrow)

      (defun mix-format-on-save ()
        (when (eq major-mode 'elixir-mode)
          (elixir-format)))

      ;; display full buffer path in title window

      ;;(setq frame-title-format
      ;;      (list (format "%s %%S: %%j " (system-name))
      ;;            '(buffer-file-name "%f" (dired-directory dired-directory "%b"))))

      (global-prettify-symbols-mode 0)
      (setq prettify-symbols-unprettify-at-point t)

      (setq prettify-symbols-alist
            '(
              ("lambda" . 955) ; λ
              ("->" . 8594)    ; →
              ("<-" . 8592)
              ("=>" . 8658)    ; ⇒
              ("<=" . 8656)
              ("|>" . 10503)
              ))

      (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'prettify-symbols-mode)
    )
```

Comment: If `prettify-symbols-mode` is not being enabled, and this is only an issue for `.ex` files then undoubtedly the major mode used for `.ex` files does *not* derive from `prog-mode`.  Just add `prettify-symbols-mode` to the mode hook for the major mode in question.

Comment: You're right about that - works it .py files just fine.

still though, when I set `(add-hook 'elixir-mode-hook 'prettify-symbols-mode)` or `(add-hook 'alchemist-mode-hook 'prettify-symbols-mode)` I still don't get the expected behavior.

Comment: Oh, this is also (or entirely?) a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46529/454 -- you're not setting `prettify-symbols-alist` *in* a mode hook function.

Comment: It very well may be. I'm new to elisp - do I need to bind it to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comments...

A third-party `elixir-mode` is being used for `.ex` files.

It's *possible* that `elixir-mode` does not derive from `prog-mode`, in which case you would need to enable `prettify-symbols-mode` in `elixir-mode-hook`; but the more apparent issue is that `prettify-symbols-alist` is not being set in the `.ex` buffer (refer to this related Q&A https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46531/454 ).

You should configure `prettify-symbols-alist` for the needs of `elixir-mode` in `elixir-mode-hook`. e.g.:

```el
(defun my-elixir-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `elixir-mode' behaviours."
  (setq prettify-symbols-alist
        '(
          ("lambda" . 955) ; λ
          ("->" . 8594)    ; →
          ("<-" . 8592)
          ("=>" . 8658)    ; ⇒
          ("<=" . 8656)
          ("|>" . 10503)
          )))

(add-hook 'elixir-mode-hook 'my-elixir-mode-hook)
```

You can also add `(prettify-symbols-mode 1)` to that custom function if necessary.

---

The `(setq prettify-symbols-alist ...)` in your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function is not useful, and can be removed.  (It is setting the value only for whichever buffer is current at the point in time that this function is evaluated during start-up.)

Comment: This was a fantastic explanation. thanks.