# How to have Emacs display different text from that stored in buffer?

Tags: font-lock

How can I get a buffer to display text that is

1. different from the text stored on disk,
2. updates as the buffer is modified, and
3. replaces one string with another string every time it occurs?

I'd like a buffer to display different characters from what is stored.  However, unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600347/22707715), I might need to have multiple characters replace the given text.  I know this should be possible, because `org-mode` manages to do it for links.  But reading that codebase seems like overkill for solving this problem...

I tried to drag-and-drop the linked solution, changing the latter string to have multiple characters.  Emacs overlays the characters of the string on top of one another instead of concatenating them when the following are set (Emacs draws the `O` and `X` on top of one another).

```lisp
(defconst my-font-lock-seq-1
  '(("ab" "Y") ("abb" "OX")))
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords-1
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            `(,(concat "\\(" (car x) "\\)")
              (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) ,(cadr x)) nil))))
          my-font-lock-seq-1))
```

I also looked over [replacing display specs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html) in the manual, but this causes other issues: (1) when I delete characters, the display is not updated if there is no longer a match (typing `ab` and then backspace, the buffer still has `Y`) and (2) if there are multiple matches, they are replaced by a single match (typing `abab` yields a single `Y`).

```lisp
(defconst my-font-lock-seq-2
  '(("ab" "Y") ("abb" "OX")))
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords-2
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            `(,(concat "\\(" (car x) "\\)")
              (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 'display ,(cadr x)) nil))))
          my-font-lock-seq-2))
```

To reproduce these issues, you can load the following with `emacs -Q`:

```
(defun attempt-1 (x)
  `(,(concat "\\(" (car x) "\\)")
    (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) ,(cadr x)) nil))))

(defun attempt-2 (x)
  `(,(concat "\\(" (car x) "\\)")
    (0 (progn (put-text-property (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 'display ,(cadr x)) nil))))

(defun my-mode ()
  "MY MODE!"
  (interactive)
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(my-font-lock-keywords))
  (setq major-mode 'my-mode)
  (setq mode-name "MyMode"))

(defconst my-font-lock-seq
  '(("ab" "Y") ("abb" "OX")))

(defconst my-font-lock-keywords
  (mapcar 'attempt-1 my-font-lock-seq))
```

Now to reproduce any behaviour described above, one need only `M-x my-mode` (possibly changing the last line to reproduce the second set of errors).

Comment: The question isn't clear. It should be standalone, not requiring referral to another question. The question seems to suppose the missing question, and asks about a partially implemented solution. What's the problem/question?

Comment: @Drew I updated the question with a direct question at the beginning.  please let me know if it still needs clarification.

Comment: Thx.................

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to drag-and-drop the linked solution, changing the latter string to have multiple characters. Emacs overlays the characters of the string on top of one another

You need to read the `compose-region` documentation, paying particular attention to the cross-referenced `reference-point-alist` docs.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34882/454 for a different example using such a "concatenated" sequence of composed characters.

(There are other ways to replace text; but if `compose-region` is involved then you need to deal with these character composition rules.)

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

As [phils noted in their answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80145/38902), `compose-region` requires more information to offset the glyphs.  The following version of `my-font-lock-keywords` resolves all the issues mentioned in the question.

```
(defconst my-font-lock-keywords
  `(("\\(ab\\)" (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) ?Y) nil)))
    ("\\(abb\\)" (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) '(?O (Br . Bl) ?X)) nil)))))
```