# prettify combined characters

Tags: prettify-symbols-mode

I would like to prettify combined characters as x̂.
The code should be something like

`(push '("\\hat{x}" . 120) prettify-symbols-alist)  ;; x̂`

Any suggestions how to accomplish visually correct prettification?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Is this about LaTeX/TeX? Try to find appropriate tags. `faces` is probably not appropriate, but I don't know what is.

Comment: Did you read `C-h v prettify-symbols-alist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the EDIT for a simpler method that is applicable to this case, although it might not be applicable in more complicated cases]

---

I got a strong hint from @phils's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34882/14825) to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34808/using-prettify-symbols-with-strings-instead-of-characters).

Basically, AFAICT there is no Unicode code point for `x̂`( see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%CC%82): it is a composed symbol consisting of a small latin letter x (code point U+0078 - decimal 120 as you point out) and a circumflex (code point U+0302 - decimal 770) stacked on top of each other. There is a way to do that in Emacs: `C-h v prettify-symbols-alist`, `C-h f compose-region` and looking at the documentation of its third argument, which says:

```
If it is a vector or list, it is a sequence of alternate characters and
composition rules, where (2N)th elements are characters and (2N+1)th
elements are composition rules to specify how to compose (2N+2)th
elements with previously composed N glyphs.

A composition rule is a cons of global and new glyph reference point
symbols.  See the documentation of ‘reference-point-alist’ for more
details.
```

was enough to guess that I would need something like `(?x <rule> 770)`. The documentation of the rules is in the doc string of `reference-point-alist` which is where I was stuck until the link above pushed me in the right direction: the correct rule is `(tc . bc)` resulting in the following incantation:

```el
(push '("\\hat{x}" . (?x (tc . bc) 770)) prettify-symbols-alist)
```

which displays the string "\hat{x}" using the glyph that is composed as follows: take the glyph for the small latin letter `x` and combine it with the glyph whose code point is 770 (the circumflex) using the composition rule `(tc . bc)` which puts at the top-center of the glyph that comes before the rule (the `x`) the bottom-center of the glyph that comes after the rule (the `^` whose code point in decimal is 770). The effect is to stack the circumflex on top of the `x`.

You might  need to toggle `prettify-symbols-mode` after you do the `push` in order for the change to take effect in the buffer.

---

EDIT: As @phils points out in a comment, there is an easier way. 770 is the code point of `COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT` which is *designed* to be stacked on top of other characters. So you only need to make a string containing the two characters at code points 120 and 770 and you are done:

```
(push `("\\hat{x}" . ,(string 120 770)) prettify-symbols-alist)
```

Here we calculate the string by evaluating the `string` function on the sequence of characters, but you can even *type* the string literally:

```
(push '("\\hat{x}" . "x̂") prettify-symbols-alist)
```

To get  that `"x̂"`, I typed: `"x C-x 8 RET COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT RET "`.

As long as you can produce your desired glyph with combining characters, you can use a string for the replacement, not only in `prettify-symbols-alist` but wherever `compose-region` is used. But the composition-rule method in the original answer might still be useful in rare cases.

Comment: I think (suspect) `COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT` (770) is designed to just be overlaid directly on another character, so `"x̂"` might be the right composition?  (Rather than `(?x (tc . bc) 770)`).  For my default font at least, that looks the way I'd expect.

Comment: All I know about composing characters is basically what's in the answer: I do use COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (770) in it - are you saying there is a simpler way to do the composition (perhaps no rule needed)?

Comment: Yes, in the absence of particular composition rules the characters just get displayed directly on top of one another, so just a string of those two characters in sequence seems like it does the trick.

Comment: See also "If it is a string..." in `C-h f compose-region`

Comment: I don't know how the default composition decides how to combine things, but for me I need to introduce an additional vertical offset to get the same effect as the string-based approach when using explicit composition rules.  Something like `(?x (tc bc 0 20) ?̂)` (that format being described by `reference-point-alist`, at the end).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I edited the answer to add the simpler method. Let me know if it needs improvement.

Comment: Also of note, the system I'm testing on uses `Ubuntu Mono` as a default font, and for whatever reason the composition is misaligned when using that font (for *any* of the approaches mentioned above).  So (as a note to Alois), if it's not working then try other fonts before assuming the syntax is bad.

Comment: Changes look good (although you could add the missing space to `tc. bc` from the original text, as that keeps jumping out at me :)  I'd up-vote, but I already did!

Comment: Done and thanks! BTW, I use Liberation Mono as my font and scaled it to a large size - I cannot see any difference between the two versions in this font.